# Poisson equation on noncompact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete non-compact manifold with bounded geometry, such that the Sobolev embeddings hold and $C^\infty_c$-functions are dense in $L^p_k$ space.

For the equation 
$$\Delta u=f,$$
for some $f\in L^2(M)$.

**Q** How can we find a solution $u\in L^2$ satisfies the above equation?

Is there any related work?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, for any noncompact Riemannian manifold $M$ (not necessarily with bounded geometry) and for any distribution $f$, there is a distribution $u$ such that $Du=f$, where $D$ is an elliptic operator satisfying the unique continuation property.

This was proved by Malgrange in `Existence et approximation des solutions des  ́equations aux d ́eriv ́ees partielles et des  ́equations de convolution'. The Euclidean case was discussed in Hormander's book`Linear partial differential operators' (Chapter 4 as I remembered), and the arguments therein carries over to general Riemannian manifolds.

There is also a constructive proof due to Li and Tam, which is easier to read for geometers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you name the title of the Li-Tam's paper.

Comment: Symmetric Green's Functions on Complete Manifolds.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replying. Might I ask a further Question: If $f$ belongs $L^{p}_k$, can we say that $u\in L^p_{k+2}$ for $k\geq0$. Namely, the regularity for $\Delta$

Comment: Not an expert, just happened to know Malgrange's result. I think you may look at Hormander's book or `Differentiable Manifold' by de Rahm. Certain regularity is discussed, but maybe not in term of Sobolev spaces.